# PHP Echos and headers - Echos not being outputted

Tags: php, html, header, echo, output-buffering

I have a section by which if a Session variable username is not in place, the application should output an error message stating that Credentials are required and then redirect the user to a login page. The issue is that, only the latter is happening, and the "error message" is not being outputted.

```
<?php if (!isset($_SESSION['username'])){  
    ob_start();
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Not logged in. Please input required credentials.');</script>";
    header('location: /se7en/login.php');
    ob_end_flush();

}
?>
```

I tried using an *Output Buffer* to counteract this issue, however, the same issue kept happening. How can I resolve this, please?

Many thanks!

Comment: You're not supposed to output anything before setting headers, and with this you're trying to redirect from the page you're trying to display output on...since you're using session variables (or lack thereof), why are you not just checking on the page you're redirecting to and display the text there?

Comment: How about using javascript for your redirect? `window.location.replace("/se7en/login.php");`

Comment: Like @cteski said, you're printing to a page, and then redirecting away from that page. You're never going to see that message. I'll make an answer to show you how I usually handle this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually handle this need by having the page I'm redirecting to post the message. One way would be this:

```
<?php if (!isset($_SESSION['username'])){  
    ob_start();
    header('location: /se7en/login.php?message=Not logged in. Please input required credentials.');
    ob_end_flush();

}
?>
```

Then on your login.php you'd have

```
if ( ! empty( $_GET['message'] ) ) {
    $message = htmlspecialchars( $_GET['message'] );
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message');</script>";
}
```

You could also just pass a message number (`message=1`) and then have all the possible messages in an array in your login.php file:

```
$messages = array(
    1 => "Not logged.....",
    2 => "something else...",
    //...
);
if( ! empty( $_GET['message'] ) && ! empty( $messages[ $_GET['message'] ] ) {
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('{$messages[ $_GET['message'] ]}');</script>";
}
```

Comment: You're welcome. The second way is way more secure, by the way.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @khartnett.

Since you are doing a header redirect, it will redirect the page before you had the chance to show the alert box.

If you do:

```
<?php if (!isset($_SESSION['username'])){  
ob_start();
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>" .
          "alert('Not logged in. Please input required credentials.');" .
          "window.location.href = '/se7en/login.php';" .
     "</script>";
header('location: /se7en/login.php');
ob_end_flush();
}
?>
```

Then, it will display the alert box which blocks further execution of the script until OK is pressed, then continues to redirect via `window.location.href`.